# locking class members from other threads

Tags: c++

I need to lock private class member for other threads: if i do not unlock variable, other threads can not use that variable, and wait before it unlocks. (something like mutex).

For example:

```
using namespace std;
class a
{
public:
    a() {
    //here i need to lock my variable
    thread th([this] {
    Sleep(10000);
    variable = 100;});
    //here i need to unlock my variable});

    }

    int getVariable() { return this->variable; }

private:
    int variable;
};



int main() {
    a var;

    thread th([&var] {cout << var.getVariable() << endl; });
    //getVariable waits before variable is unlocked
}
```

Comment: Ehh, why don't you just use a `std::mutex`?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl sorry, i'm new to multi threaded programming, but as i know i can't lock variables with mutex, what did you mean?

Comment: @Алексей You can't lock arbitrary variables at all.  What you can do is guard access to your variable using a mutex.

Comment: @Алексей You can have a mutex for every variable you need to lock. Every thread will then need to lock/unlock the mutex before/after accessing the variable it protects. Getting that right is up to you.

Comment: @JesperJuhl so i need to lock getVariable?

Comment: You need a lock (aka, `std::mutex`, etc) for `variable`, which `getVariable()` can lock before reading from `variable` and unlock afterwards, and that your `std::thread` can lock before writing to `variable` and unlock afterwards. However, since your `variable` is just a simple `int`, consider using `std::atomic<int>` instead, no mutex needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't lock arbitrary variables.  What you need to do is guard access to your shared variable using a mutex or other synchronization object.  For example:

```
class a
{
public:
    a() {
        std::thread th([this] {
            std::lock_guard lock(variable_mutex);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
            variable = 100;
        });
        th.detach(); // you probably actually want to store th somewhere instead
    }

    int getVariable() {
        std::lock_guard lock(variable_mutex);
        return this->variable;
    }

private:
    int variable;
    std::mutex variable_mutex;
};

int main() {
    a var;
    std::cout << var.getVariable() << '\n';
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d21bc25a7f92c714)

This will prevent both the main thread and the thread started in `a`'s constructor from accessing `variable` at the same time.  The demo I included highlights a problem with this though.  It's possible that the main thread could lock the mutex before the thread that initializes it.  If this is a problem in your case, you could instead use an event/flag class.  The standard library doesn't provide one, but it's possible to build one out of a mutex and a condition variable:

```
class Event
{
public:
    Event()
        : is_set{false}
    {
    }

    void set()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        is_set = true;
        cond_var.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        cond_var.wait(lock, [this]() { return is_set; });
    }

private:
    bool is_set;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
};

class a
{
public:
    a() {
        std::thread th([this] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
            variable = 100;
            variable_initialized.set();
        });
        th.detach(); // you probably actually want to store th somewhere instead
    }

    int getVariable() {
        variable_initialized.wait();
        return variable;
    }

private:
    int variable;
    Event variable_initialized;
};

int main() {
    a var;
    std::cout << var.getVariable() << '\n';
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8140189d023912a)

Note that this flag-based approach only works if, as in the example, `variable` is only written to once.  Some other approach would be needed if it's possible for `variable` to change later.  In the end, the exact type of synchronization needed will depend on the specifics of your situation.  There are many ways to synchronize access to data across threads, and that's one of the things that makes writing multithreaded programs challenging.

Comment: For your 1st example, a simpler alternative would be to use `std::atomic<int>` instead of `int`. No `std::mutex` needed. In your 2nd example, you still have a race condition on `variable`. Even though you use a `std::conditional_variable` to signal changes to `variable`, you still need to synchronize access to `variable` itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It seems like OP wants readers to block for the full sleep duration, which is why I didn't mention that.  My assumption is that the sleep represents some long-running task during which the value of `variable` isn't meaningful, though that assumption my be incorrect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added an extra paragraph re the second part of your comment.  In this particular situation a one-time flag is enough, but there are plenty of situations where that isn't the case.